# Multipeer connectivity not accepting connection

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I'm building an app which can share images using MPC when the sender select host a session and the receiver select join session and select the sender device name it is not connecting to the sender it is displaying declined. Is there is an permission needed to be added in info.plist file? Sender is a physical device iPhone 7 and receiver who join the session is a simulator iPhone SE 2nd generation.

The below is the screen shot of simulator
And iam not getting the invitation alert in the host device

[image: Simulator join session browser showing declined]

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity


class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate,MCSessionDelegate {
 
    
 
    
    var selectedimage: UIImage!
    

    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var images = [UIImage]()
    
    
    var  peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.model)
    var mcsession: MCSession?
    var mcadvertiser: MCAdvertiserAssistant?
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        imageCollectionView.delegate = self
        imageCollectionView.dataSource = self
        
        peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.model)
        mcsession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
        
        
        
        mcsession?.delegate = self
        
        
    
        
        
    }

    @IBAction func joinsessionclicked(_ sender: Any) {
        
        
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Select a option", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Host", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            
            self.mcadvertiser = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "ksb-sendit125", discoveryInfo: nil, session: self.mcsession!)
            
         
            
            
            self.mcadvertiser?.start()
            
        }))
        
        
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Join", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            let mcbrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "ksb-sendit125", session: self.mcsession!)
            
            mcbrowser.delegate = self
            
            
            self.present(mcbrowser, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        
        
        present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        
        
     
        
        
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ImageCell
        {
            cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
            cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.39)
            
            return cell
        }
        
        
        return UICollectionViewCell()
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Select an option", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send iT", style: .default, handler:{(action)
            in
            
       
            
            guard let mcsession = self.mcsession else { return}
            
            if mcsession.connectedPeers.count > 0
            {
                if let imageData = self.selectedimage.pngData()
                {
                    do
                    {
                        try mcsession.send(imageData, toPeers: mcsession.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
                    }
                    
                    catch
                    {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
            
            
            
            
        }))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remove", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) in
            
            self.images.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.imageCollectionView.reloadData()
            
        }))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
        present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
  









@IBAction func addImagebtnclicked(_ sender: Any) {
    
    
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    
   
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    
    
    
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
    
    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage  else {
        return
    }
    
    self.selectedimage = image
    
    
    images.append(image)
    
    imageCollectionView.reloadData()
    
   

    
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true , completion: nil)
}













func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}




func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
    
    switch state {
    case .connected:
        print("Connected \(peerID.displayName)")
        break
    
    case .connecting:
        print("Connecting  \(peerID.displayName)")
        break
    
    case .notConnected:
        print("Not Connected \(peerID.displayName)")
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let  image = UIImage(data: data)
        {
            self.images.insert(image, at: 0)
            
            self.imageCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    
}


func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
    
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {
    
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you testing your app with the simulator?  I won't inspect your code because you have so many empty lines, which makes it difficult to read.

Comment: Ok I found the solution I have replaced MCAdvertiserAssistant with McNearbyServiceAdvertiser now it works Thank you for your response